# Tweepy Stream Stop/Start Programatically

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, tweepy

I am trying to build a web application using Django to track tweets by hashtags. I am using Tweepy Asyncstreaming and it's working fine. I am new to async programming. I need help with how to stop the running stream and start a new stream when a new hashtag is added.

Here is my code:

```
import os

from tweepy.asynchronous import AsyncStream 
import asyncio


consumer_key = os.getenv('XXXXXXXXXXX')
consumer_secret = os.getenv('XXXXXXXXXXX')
access_token = os.getenv('XXXXXXXXXXX')
access_token_secret = os.getenv('XXXXXXXXXXX')


async def main():
    stream = TweetStream(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
                        access_token, access_token_secret)
    await stream.filter(follow=['web3', 'crypto'])


class TweetStream(AsyncStream):
    async def on_connect(self):
        print('Stream connected')

    async def on_status(self, status):
        if status.in_reply_to_user_id == None and not(status.entities['user_mentions']):
            print(status.text)
            print(status.user.screen_name)
    
    async def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```